# Python, Kivy, Labels keep switching places every time I hit run, is this a bug?

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.clock import Clock
import character
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label

    self.background=Image(source="Pics\\backgroundtemp.png",pos_hint ={"x":0,"y":0.2})
    self.add_widget(self.background)
    for i in range (3):
        self.playerR[i] = character.Character("DIO","R",size_hint=(0.35,0.35),pos_hint={"x":0.7,"y":0.4})
        self.playerL[i] = character.Character("DIO","L",size_hint=(0.35,0.35),pos_hint={"x":-0.05,"y":0.4})
    self.add_widget(self.playerR[0])
    self.add_widget(self.playerL[0])
    print self.width
    self.abilityLabel = [Label(text=i.name, font_size=30, color = (1, 1, 1, 1)) for i in self.playerL[0].abilities]
    self.abilityLabel.insert(0, Label(text="switch", font_size=30, color= (1, 1, 1, 1), pos_hint={"x": 0.05, "y": -0.35}))
    self.abilityLabel[1].pos_hint = {"x": -0.4, "y": -0.3}
    self.abilityLabel[2].pos_hint = {"x": -0.15, "y": -0.3}
    self.abilityLabel[3].pos_hint = {"x": -0.4, "y": -0.45}
    self.abilityLabel[4].pos_hint = {"x": -0.15, "y": -0.45}
    self.nameLabels =[Label(text = self.playerL[0].name), Label(text = self.playerR[0].name)]
    self.nameLabels[0].pos_hint = {"x":-0.4, "y": 0.45}
    self.nameLabels[1].pos_hint = {"x": 0.4, "y": 0.45}
    self.imageAbility = [Image(source = "Pics\AbilityTempBack.png", allow_stretch= True,keep_ratio = False,size_hint = (0.15,0.1)) for i in range(5)]
    self.imageAbility[0] = Image(source="Pics\AbilityTempBack.png", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False,size_hint=(0.1, 0.1))

    self.imageAbility[0].pos_hint = {"x": 0.5, "y": 0.1}
    self.imageAbility[1].pos_hint = {"x": 0.05, "y": 0.15}
    self.imageAbility[2].pos_hint = {"x": 3, "y": 0.1}
    self.imageAbility[3].pos_hint = {"x": 3, "y": 0.1}
    self.imageAbility[4].pos_hint = {"x": 3, "y": 0.1}

    for i in range(len(self.imageAbility)):
        self.add_widget(self.imageAbility[i])

    for i in range(len(self.abilityLabel)):
        self.add_widget(self.abilityLabel[i])

    for i in range(2):
        self.nameLabels[i].font_size = 40
        self.add_widget(self.nameLabels[i])
```

Here is character

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class Character(Image):  # Character is also Image
    def __init__(self, name, side, **kwargs):
        super(Character, self).__init__(**kwargs)  # because we defined char as an image we need this sentence
        self.name = name
        self.side = side
        self.health = 100
        self.maxHealth = 100
        self.strength = 100
        self.defense = 100
        self.attack_speed = 100
        self.speedBuff = 1
        self.powerBuff = 1
        self.defenseBuff = 1
        self.abilities = {Ability("temp1" , side),Ability("temp2" , side),Ability("temp3" ,side),Ability("temp4",side)}
        self.source = "Pics\chr"+name+side+".png"
```

Anyway, it seems like a bug, and it is really frustrating, because it is truly random, and it changes every couple of times i hit run on the code, might be a problem with kivy itself rather than a problem with something else, and here is a pic of how it is intended vs how it shows up sometimes

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please share an example of what you expect vs what you are getting?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lv10dz

Comment: You are storing your collection of `Ability`s in a set - which has no specified iteration order.  You probably want a list instead.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ok, so basically I am creating a Pokemon battles style game, I am working on the first stage which is to create the UI and the graphics, I already did the back ground and the Characters, and now i am adding the ability icons which are just a plain red rectangle, and each ability name is called temp+number, in the pic i sent it shows how it is supposed to look, top 2 abilities being temp 1 and temp 2, and the bottom being temp 3 and temp 4, now everytime i try and rerun the program, the places of the temp 1 and temp 4 get mixed, i assume it is a bug in kivy and not in the code.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you very much, solved

Comment: Hello, can you share your solution in an answer, in case people in the future may encounter a similar one, your experience benefit them? Thanks!